# Pygame sound when started from terminal, not from Nodered

Tags: python, pygame, node-red

I want Nodered to play my MP3s. I wrote a script which plays fine from terminal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys
import pygame
print(sys.version)
file = '/home/pi/Musik/02-black_light_burns-animal.mp3'
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(file)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy(): 
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

Same script played by nodered using the pythonshell node does not provide sound. I can see it is the same python envoirement, same compiler and so on.:

> pygame 1.9.4.post1 Hello from the pygame community.
> https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
> 2.7.16 (default, Oct 10 2019, 22:02:15)  [GCC 8.3.0]

I have checked the mixer settings which are also identical. IsBusy() returns 1 in both cases. However, terminal started is all fine, from nodered there is no sound.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you running Node-RED, is it as a service?

Comment: @hardillb: yes, it is running as a service

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into a similar issue when I was using `.mp3` file with the mixer. When I converted it to a `.wav` it is working for months now. So try to convert the `.mp3` file to a `.wav` and call it in code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys
import pygame
print(sys.version)
file = '/home/pi/Musik/02-black_light_burns-animal.wav'
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(file)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy(): 
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

Comment: Just tried, sadly same behaviour: terminal outputs sound, Nodered does not.

Comment: @Inso that's the Nodered issue then. It is mainly designed for node.js not python. Try this code with another IDE such as Pycharm for example.