# Why does my Python code only play sound through my Bluetooth speaker in the IDE, but not the console?

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to make a soundboard with my Raspberry Pi 3B+ on the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS (as of 5/1/22), but I'm running into a pretty big issue. My goal with this program is to run it headless, and have it output sound to a Bluetooth speaker. The problem is that the only time it works is when I run the code in the IDE (Thonny). I tried to force PyGame to use the Bluetooth speaker `mixer.init(devicename = 'TYLT')`
but it still didn't work. My code is listed below:

```
from pygame import mixer
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) 
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

mixer.init(devicename = 'TYLT')
mixer.music.load('/home/gerson/Downloads/bleep.ogg')
mixer.music.play()


while True: # Run forever
    if GPIO.input(10) == GPIO.HIGH:
        mixer.music.unpause()
    else:
        mixer.music.pause()
```

Any help is appreciated, as I've spent about 3 days trying to figure this out.

Comment: Just a guess: try adding " if __ name __ == '__ main __ ': " before calling your functional code, but after the imports. Edit: it re-formats my comment if I have "__" without a space, but name and main should not have a space next to them.

Comment: You might want to take a look on the raspberrypi stackexchange site. Here's a related question though it's a few years old so might not be applicable to the latest audio drivers on the pi: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/68127/144439

Comment: @Mandias sorry for not understanding, but what specifically would I use as 'name' and 'main'?

Comment: @cguk70 unfortunately, no Bluetooth devices appear as a sound car/hardware device, so this sadly does not work.

Comment: @GersonCampos see this site for some examples/explanations: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/if-name-main-python-example/. The reason that I suggested it is because some libraries can be picky about using it, but don't necessarily tell you so.

Comment: Is the raspberry pi connecting to the bluetooth device do you know? I just tried your code (albeit without the GPIO control) using a raspberry pi zero 2 w and the latest raspbian and it worked. However the speaker didn't auto connect if I didn't go into the GUI first. To get it to connect without running the GUI I used bluetoothctl using `paired-devices` to get the MAC and then `connect <MAC>` to manually connect the speaker.

Comment: @cguk yes it was paired, my speaker makes a little noise when it connects, and I even tested a YouTube video, which worked, but the console still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other file formats than .ogg?
In this post, using the .wav format instead of the .mp3 format was the solution
[Pygame sound when started from terminal, not from Nodered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853263/pygame-sound-when-started-from-terminal-not-from-nodered)